# Tricky SQL query

Tags: sql, join

Really tricky SQL statement I have here. Trying to build this query for about hour.
Maybe You can help me.

We have a table with 3 columns:
gamename | user | times_played

The query should select top three games (depending total times_played) and top three user who has played most times in this game => 9 rows.

```
The result is like:
CounterStrike | Smith 
CounterStrike | Jonny
Counterstrike | Hans
WoW           | George
WoW           | Bob
Wow           | Frank
Need For Speed| James
Need For Speed| Marion
Need For Speed| Scarlet
```

Would be very nice, if you could help me =)
Thanks!

Comment: What database? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Which technology? MySQL? SQL Server? Can you use a stored procedure?

Comment: @foriamstu better question: *should* you use a stored procedure?   In my experience, almost always: 'no'.    Seems handy at the time, comes back to bite you in maintenance.

Comment: @TM I would say you have a very easy life if you've rarely had to use an SP. ;)

Unfortunately once a problem goes past a certain point of complexity (or has more than one action required) it becomes necessary to solve a problem with more than one query. It then becomes better to solve it in an SP. Benefits include maintenance of session (temporary parameters/data) between queries, and more efficient code (as SP's are pre-compiled).

Answer (score 13):

**Update:**

As `@Steve Kass` pointed out, I didn't notice that you only wanted the first three games.

Here's the updated version:

In `SQL Server`, `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  gamename, user
FROM    (
        SELECT  r.gamename, user,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY game ORDER BY times_played DESC) rn,
        FROM    (
                SELECT  gamename, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(times_played) DESC) AS game_rn
                FROM    results
                GROUP BY
                        gamename
                ) g
        JOIN    results r
        ON      r.gamename = g.gamename
        WHERE   game_rn <= 3
        ) q
WHERE   rn <= 3
ORDER BY
        gamename, times_played DESC
```

In `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  ro.gamename, ro.user
FROM    (
        SELECT  gamename, SUM(times_played) AS rank
        FROM    results
        ORDER BY
                rank DESC
        LIMIT 3
        ) rd
JOIN    results ro
ON      ro.gamename >= rd.gamename
        AND ro.gamename <= rd.gamename
        AND
        (ro.times_played, ro.id) <=
        (
        SELECT  ri.times_played, ri.id
        FROM    results ri
        WHERE   ri.gamename = rd.gamename
        ORDER BY
                ri.times_played DESC, ri.id DESC
        LIMIT 2, 1
        )
ORDER BY
        gamename, times_played DESC
```

You will need a `PRIMARY KEY` for this query to work, assuming it is called `id`.

This is explained in more detail in this article in my blog:

- [**Advanced row sampling**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/)

In `PostgreSQL 8.3` and below:

```
SELECT  gamename, ((ri)[s]).user
FROM    (
        SELECT  gamename, ri, generate_series(1, 3) AS s
        FROM    (
                SELECT  ro.gamename,
                        ARRAY
                        (
                        SELECT  ri
                        FROM    results ri
                        WHERE   ri.gamename = ro.gamename
                        ORDER BY
                                times_played DESC
                        LIMIT 3
                        ) AS ri
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  gamename, SUM(times_played) AS rank
                        FROM    results
                        ORDER BY
                                rank DESC
                        LIMIT 3
                        ) rd
                ) q
        ) q2
ORDER BY
        gamename, s
```

Comment: It just seems so easy when you answer it :-)

Comment: I suppose it's "PARTITION BY"

Comment: I'd throw in an order by Game and rn to be sure that the results are displayed in the proper order.

Comment: Fixed `PARTITION` and added `ORDER BY` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Quassnoi noticed that you asked for the top users *only for the top three games (based on total times_played)*. Here's a query for that (not tested on real data, since no CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements were given). I also include ties, which Quassnoi didn't, just to show you that option.

```
with GamesPlays(gamename,totalPlays) as (
  select
    gamename, sum(times_played)
  from results
  group by gamename
), GamesRanked(gamename,gameRank) as (
  select
    gamename,
    rank() over (
      order by totalPlays desc
    )
  from GamesPlays
), ResultsRanked(gamename,user,userRank) as (
  select
    gamename,
    user,
    rank() over (
      partition by user
      order by times_played desc
    )
  from results;
)
  select
    G.gamename, R.user
  from ResultsRanked as R
  join GamesRanked as G
  on G.gamename = R.gamename
  where gameRank <= 3
  and userRank <= 3
  order by 
  gameRank,userRank;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. There are `12` upvotes and none made but a simgle remark :)

Comment: Maybe what you post is so rarely wrong that people figure it's a waste of time to look closely. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE #game_stats


CREATE TABLE #game_stats (gamename VARCHAR(50),users VARCHAR(50),times_played INT);

INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('Counter Strike','Kamesh',2);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('Counter Strike','Hely',4);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('Counter Strike','Maitri',1);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('Counter Strike','Laxmi',5);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('WOW','Kamesh',21);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('WOW','laxmi',60);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('WOW','Hely',7);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('NFS','Hely',5);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('NFS','Kamesh',1);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('NFS','Maitri',12);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('NFS','Laxmi',21);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('CODE ZERO','Kamesh',45);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('CODE ZERO','Maitri',52);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('CODE ZERO','Laxmi',21);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('CODE ZERO','Kamesh',41);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('HITMAN','Maitri',142);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('HITMAN','Laxmi',210);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('HITMAN','Kamesh',41);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('HITMAN','Maitri',102);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('HITMAN','Mani',142);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('NFS','Mani',210);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('CODE ZERO','Mani',41);
INSERT INTO #game_stats VALUES ('WOW','Mani',102);

select * from #game_stats;

SELECT  RN,
Gamename,
Users,
Times_played
FROM
(
   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GS.gamename ORDER BY SUM(GS.times_played) DESC) AS RN,
      GS.gamename,
      GS.users,
      SUM(gs.times_played) as times_played

FROM #game_stats GS
WHERE GS.gamename IN (
            SELECT  TOP 3 gamename
                            FROM #game_stats 
                            GROUP BY gamename 
                                                              ORDER BY sum(times_played) DESC
                     ) 
GROUP BY GS.gamename,GS.users
) a
WHERE RN<=3
ORDER BY gamename,times_played DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT GN,US,GT,UT
FROM
(SELECT GN,US,GT,UT,
        Dense_rank() over(ORDER BY GT DESC) RGT,
        Dense_rank() over(partition BY GN ORDER BY UT DESC) RUT
FROM
    (SELECT gamename GN,
            users US,
            times_played TP,
            sum(times_played) over (partition BY gamename) GT ,
            sum(times_played) over (partition BY gamename,users) UT
    FROM game_stats))
WHERE RGT <4
AND RUT < 4
ORDER BY GT DESC,
        UT DESC
```